# configurable subset of services under service locator pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, solid-principles

In a Java 8 / Spring 5 project:

Assume an Interface (e.g. `IBase`) with 3 concrete implementations (e.g. `IBaseImplA`, `IBaseImplB`, `IBaseImplC`) operating under a `Service Locator Pattern`.

Assume a set of classes (e.g `ValidatorA`, `ValidatorB` ... `ValidatorN`) which all implement the Interface `Validator` that need to be executed to validate a request.

They are loaded dynamically through the `application.properties` file via an `enabled` property (per class). During runtime (`init` method), if `enabled` is `true` they will be added to a `Set<Validator>` which will later be iterated and for each `Validator` the `validate(Request req)` method will be invoked.

Which is the best way to have a configurable subset of the aforementioned validators for each concrete implementation without violating the `SOLID` principles?

PS> I have investigated the `Rules Pattern` for my case and it doesn't seem to apply.

PS2> Example of what I'm trying to accomplish: `IBaseImplA` will need to have `ValitorA` executed; `IBaseImplB` will need to have `ValidatorB` and `ValidatorC` executed; `IBaseImplC` will need to have all validators executed. The above example should be done in a configurable manner.

Comment: Not easy to answer without more explicit domain details. Some approach I've seen is relying on interfaces e.g. `Request implements HasContactInfo` then `ContactInfoValidator implements Validator<HasContactInfo>` and use the container at runtime to load the set of validators.

Comment: @plalx I believe it's more clear now.